# Rotating a square towards a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

I'm trying to make the `shooter0` rotate towards the character (which will be moving around constantly). I tried to using the `atan()` and then converting that to an angle but the `shooter0` won't rotate.

```
var shooter0 = document.getElementById('shooter0');
var character = document.getElementById('character');
var tracker0 = shooter0.getContext('2d');
// The cordinates for the character and shooter0
var characterLeft = 530;
var characterTop = 180;
var shooter0Left = 960;
var shooter0Top = 470;

while (characterLeft >= 700){
  setInterval(startShooter, 1000);
}


function startShooter(){
  //Getting all the variable to be able to calculate the angle of the hypotenuse
  var dX = characterLeft - tracker0Left;
  var dY = characterTop - tracker0Top;
  var arcTan = Math.atan(dX/dY)* 180/Math.PI;

  var cx = shooter0.width/2;
  var cy = shooter0.height/2;


  tracker0.save();
  tracker0.translate(cx, cy); // pivot point
  //rotating the square towards the character
  tracker0.rotate(arcTan * Math.PI/180);
  //Drawing the square
  tracker0.fillRect(400, 300, 100, 100);
  tracker0.restore();
}
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="character" height="50px;" width="50px;"></canvas>
<canvas id="shooter0" height="100px;" width="100px;"></canvas>
```

And CSS:

```
#character{
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 530px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: orange;
}
#shooter0{
  position: absolute;
  left: 960px;
  top: 470px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #B40404;
}
```

Sorry if you find the code rather messy. Here's a fiddle with all of my code if you find that useful. https://jsfiddle.net/Snubben/tc0j4psz/3/
Please don't use any JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your fiddle to work for some reason, so I created a little example.

The thing I notice in your code:

`var arcTan = Math.atan(dX/dY)* 180/Math.PI;` : `Math.atan` returns an angle in radians. And you convert it to degrees by `180/Math.PI`

Only to convert it back to radians here again:
`tracker0.rotate(arcTan * Math.PI/180);`

Then, for calculating angles (in radians), I think `Math.atan2` is the most easy to use: [Math.atan2 - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2)

The usage of `Math.atan2` to calculate an angle between two points is:
`Math.atan2(point2.y - point1.y, point2.x - point1.x)`

With that information, I think you can get very far.

**[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1Lrt20b/)**